# custom obj which is list to Opportunity (Look up Relationship).costom obj when click check box automatically update the opportunity Handoff true

Tags: inputfield

```
trigger UpdateHandoffAttached on topx__c (after insert, after update,
after delete) {
List<Opportunity> listoppUpdate=new List<Opportunity>();
List<Opportunity> listopp=new List<Opportunity>();
Set<Id> setOppId=new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> setOppDelete=new Set<Id>();
map<id,id> mapDocAttchTrue = new map<id,id>();
map<id,id> mapDocAttchFalse = new map<id,id>();
map<id,id> mapDelete = new map<id,id>();
if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
for(topx__c ada:Trigger.New){
if(ada.Checkvalue__c ==True && ada.picklist__c=='topx1'){
mapDocAttchTrue.put(ada.Opportunity,ada.id);
setOppId.add(ada.Opportunity);
}
else
mapDocAttchFalse.put(ada.Opportunity,ada.id);
setOppId.add(ada.Opportunity);
}
}
if(Trigger.isDelete){
for(topx__c ada:Trigger.old){
mapDelete.put(ada.Opportunity,ada.id);

setOppId.add(ada.Opportunity);
setOppDelete.add(ada.Opportunity);
}
}
listopp = 'select id,Handoff__c from Opportunity where id in: setOppId';
if(listopp.size()>0 && listopp !=null){
for(Opportunity opp:listopp){
if(mapDocAttchTrue.containskey(opp.id)){
opp.Handoff__c ='Yes';
}
if(mapDocAttchFalse.containskey(opp.id)){
opp.Handoff__c = 'No';
}
if(setOppDelete.containskey(opp.id)){
opp.Handoff__c= ;
}
listoppUpdate.add(opp);
}
}
if(listoppUpdate.size()>0 && listoppUpdate!=null){
update listoppUpdate;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: line breaks not allowed in string literals at line 39 column -1

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong. In the code you posted `opp.Handoff__c = ;` won't compile but with a different message to the one you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The below line causing an issue.

```
opp.Handoff__c= ;
```

If Handoff__c is Checkbox field then,

```
opp.Handoff__c= true or false;
```

If Handoff__c is text field then as per the previous statement in your code,

```
opp.Handoff__c= 'yes' or 'no'; // For String, the value should be in single quote
```